# How do I remove desktop couch as a dependency on my application?

Tags: application-development, quickly, desktopcouch

Quickly is a great application to create gui apps for ubuntu easily and quickly. Maybe quickly use desktop-couch database as back-end database, which is a problem. I developed a gui apps using quickly. Does not use any addition package which are not default installed in ubuntu. After installation of my apps everything works fine in my pc but it shows several errors in my friend's pc which is ubuntu 11.04 installed. But he has no desktopcouch installed.

I did not use desktop-couch in my gui, so why should anyone need to install desktopcouch as dependency. Is there anyway to remove auto created desktopcouch dependency from quickly. I am new in quickly [not linux] so can not understand well.

Error:

```
  maruf@phoenix:~$ enviornment-gui-ss 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/enviornment-gui-ss", line 43, in <module>
    import enviornment_gui_ss
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/enviornment_gui_ss/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from enviornment_gui_ss import EnviornmentGuiSsWindow
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/enviornment_gui_ss/EnviornmentGuiSsWindow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from enviornment_gui_ss_lib import Window
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/enviornment_gui_ss_lib/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . preferences import preferences
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/enviornment_gui_ss_lib/preferences.py", line 19, in <module>
    from desktopcouch.records.server import CouchDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/records/server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from desktopcouch.application.server import *
ImportError: No module named application.server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your **init**.py file and comment out the following:

- preferences.update(default_preferences)
- preferences.db_connect()
- preferences.load()
- preferences.save()

And remove preferences in the following line:

- from yourProject_lib import set_up_logging, preferences, get_version

That should do it.